# iOS: MPMoviePlayer won't play

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Using the code at the bottom of this post I can successfully display a movie. However I need to now use moviePlayer as a property rather than a local variable. So by adding the following in the header file:

```
  @property (retain, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mPlayer;
```

...and synthesizing it as:

```
   @synthesize mPlayer = _mPlayer
```

Here's the original code. This works fine. All I change is the initialisation line where instead of using a local variable I use the property. A

```
  MPMoviePlayerController * mPlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
    mPlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;

    [self.welcomeImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [mPlayer.view setFrame: self.welcomeImage.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.welcomeImage addSubview:mPlayer.view];
    mPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    mPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [mPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mPlayer play];
```

I just get a black box, no controls or video. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change control style  for player

Comment: you can't play in a simulator... You need to use a device to test it out...

Comment: @NANNAV: How would that be relevant? It works fine for the local variable. I tried changing it but no luck.

@ lakesh: You can play it on the simulator, the local variable shows it just fine.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your not using your synthesized property. Change mPlayer to _mPlayer.

```
_mPlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
_mPlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;

[self.welcomeImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[_mPlayer.view setFrame: self.welcomeImage.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.welcomeImage addSubview:_mPlayer.view];
_mPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
_mPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[_mPlayer prepareToPlay];
[mPlayer play];
```

This should work as long your videoURL is valid.

Comment: Apologies, I made it a bit confusing in the post. The third block of code is the original code that works fine. If I add the synthesized property (as you've done) it sadly does not work.

Comment: Are you sure initWithContentURL:videoURL is valid?